# Is it possible to get the current playing song NOT in iPod.app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaplayercontroller

In iPhone/iPod touch current media player controls are available in the bottom of the screen, where also the title of the current playing song is displayed. It can be an any app, not only the iPod.app. As far as I know, `MPMediaPlayerController` has only the `iPodMusicPlayer` method to get the current media player. But is it possible to get somehow the current playing song from an any app?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but if the other app(s) have provided information about their now playing track in the Now Playing Info Center, it may be possible to retrieve the information about the currently playing track with the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. I know that you can set properties with this class, but not sure about retrieving - I don't see why not.

Comment: @sooper Unfortunately, it doesn't work: `nowPlayingInfo` is `nil`.

Comment: Hmm, it may be that you need to start an audio session and fire the `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` method (`UIApplication`).